# Combine multiple rows into one JSON object/array from single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to combine two rows of generated json within mysql, my current code outputs two rows (first is user id, second is the time) I want to combine them into one string. I've explored the use of *GROUP CONCAT, JSON_MERGE* (and *JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE*) and also *JSON_OBJECTAGG*. For further info, I am using *MYSQL8*.

**Current output:**

```
unavailability
{"59745190": "1400"}
{"59745190": "1200"}
```

**My MySQL Script:**

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(`appointment_with`, TIME_FORMAT(`appointment_datetime`,'%H%i')) as `unavailability`  
FROM `appointments` 
WHERE `appointment_with` =  '59745190' 
AND (DATE(`appointment_datetime`) =  '2022-03-30' AND `appointment_confirmed` = 1)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you also post your expected output so it's more clear?

Comment: {"59745190": ["1400","1200"]}

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b86c295bef065a0a9b77e27d845e4bc).